# Why is min() returning 13 and not 1?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and am running into some issues with understanding what some of the functions are doing.  Currently, I am having some issues understanding what the `min()` function is doing.

```
lst = [2,13,5,5,5,6,9,7,4,3,1]
print(lst.pop(min(lst)))
```

The output is 13 instead of 1.  If `min()` executes an iterable process, why is it returning 13?  Does this need to be in a for loop?

Comment: `min` does return 1, but what are you using `lst.pop` (which takes an index as argument) for?

Comment: `list.pop()` takes an *index*, not a *value* to be removed.  13 is at index 1 in your list.

Comment: `lst.pop(lst.index(min(lst)))` or just `lst.sort(reverse=True)` and then `lst.pop()` automatically pops the last item which is the smallest.  You can do that over and over to constantly pop the minimum value.  The best thing about popping from the end is that it's more efficient.  When you pop from somewhere else all elements after the popped element have to be shifted (copied) over by one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  I was using `pop` as part of a function to remove the smallest value from a list, return the list without the smallest value,  without mutating the list.  It was my understanding that using `lst.remove` would change the public list var.  Where `lst.pop` does not change the list var outside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it down one step at a time:

```
>>> lst = [2,13,5,5,5,6,9,7,4,3,1]
>>> min(lst)
1
>>> lst.pop(1)
13
>>> lst
[2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9, 7, 4, 3, 1]
```

`lst.pop(1)` removes element #1 (the second element, because lists are numbered from zero) and returns it.  To remove the 1 from the list, you should do [`lst.remove(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) instead, which returns `None` instead of the value removed.  You already have the value removed because you provided it in the first place.

If you are going to be doing many insertions and removals of the smallest element of the list, consider using [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to keep the list "nicely organized" for fast insertions and removals.

Answer (score 1):

`min` returns the value of the minimum, i.e. 1 in this case. But you are asking for `lst.pop(min(lst))`, i.e. `lst.pop(1)`. This removes and returns element number 1 (the second element, since elements are numbered from 0), which is 13.

Answer (score 0):

argument to pop is index - not the actual value to remove.

So, to "pop" the minimum value you would do something like:

```
lst.pop(lst.index(min(lst)))
```

You can use "remove" method to remove a given value.

```
lst.remove(min(lst))
```

Please note that the remove method does not return anything!